# Handlebars.js is returning an empty template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, koa

I am running a node server with Koa and using Handlebars for templating. I have the following template:

```
<script id="side_item" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>
       <a href="{{this.route}}"><i class="{{this.icon}}"></i> {{this.name}}</a>
    </li>
</script>
```

And my javascript code is:

```
var source = $("#side_item").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
 var html = template({
    route: "museum",
    icon: "fa fa-institution fa-fw",
    name: "Museum"
});
```

But I am getting the following source:

```
<script id="side_item" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <li>
      <a href=""><i class=""></i> </a>
   </li>
</script>
```

I assumed the script tags would be removed and the completed template would be rendered. Is it possible the brackets for the expressions are removed before handlebars can see them? Or is there something wrong with how I am compiling the template? I am following the examples at the handlebars website as closely as I can.

Comment: Are you sure? http://jsbin.com/komegajaqe/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: I also tried with tryhandlebarsjs.com and it worked, but when I try local it doesn't work: http://imgur.com/LDpuxNb. This is on chrome and safari.